# Multiply (as a Babylonian): 141 times 17 1/5

Tags: math-history

How do we multiply 141 times 17 1/5 as a Babylonian?
I wasn't sure the space between 17 and 1/5, now I see that 17 1/5 is 17.2 in our notation.

Is there a formula that I can solve this?

Any hint, comment would be very appreciated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Note that ${1\over5} = {12\over 60}$, and try to write both numbers in [sexagesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) notation. Then multiply in the same way as we multiply numbers in decimal notation. (The Babylonians would have [multiplication tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Babylonians) to help them with this.)